# VirtualBox losing left window which shows virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox

There are virtualbox machines list in left side, I drag window on the right side to far left, so the [left side disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQGCV.png).

To reset the position of UI preference, but I didn't find the menu. So how to make the left side appear again without changing user?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a very small space near the left border, the cursor turn in change in to "move line". With this you can move the line between the list of VMs and the VM Settings.

Or you change the "GUI/SplitterSizes" in the Virtualbox Config file: `~/.config/VirtualBox/Virtualbox.xml`.
e.g. from "0,1145" to "145,1000"
Best you make a backup of the file before changing anything. Just in case.

As @Yang (thanks!) mentioned in the comment, I add his remark:
Instead of editing the config file with a text editor it can be changed via the `VBoxManage` (or `vboxmanage`) command.

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/SplitterSizes "853,426"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I change the `Virtualbox.xml` but it didn't take any effect and was overwrited by the configuration which reflects the VirtualBox GUI closed before. But I found comments in `Virtualbox.xml`. **Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes**. So I used `VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/SplitterSizes "853,426"` to change the config file, and it takes effects!

Answer (score 0):

This question can be resolved by changing to another user, but it wasn't a good idea.

So this question can be solved by changing the cache of UI position in current users config/cache directory.

1. Location of VirtualBox config file. see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/vboxconfigdata.html#).
2. Use `VBoxManage` to change items(metioned by Marco above) in config file.

   `VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/SplitterSizes "853,426"`
3. Restart VirtualBox.